# filter for row containing words (string) from a different table SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

So I am trying to select all the rows that contains string equal to values from another table.

```
SELECT q.QUERY, f.ANONID 
FROM FACTS f
INNER JOIN QUERYDIM q 
ON f.QUERYID = q.ID 
WHERE q.QUERY IN (SELECT city FROM zipcodes);
```

q.QUERY is a string with different lengths
I want to select all the q.QUERY that contains value that is equal to any value in city

example

```
one row:
q.QUERY = "this is a city called berlin"
```

another row:

```
q.QUERY = "in cairo it is nice" 


SELECT city FROM zipcodes = ("berlin","Birmingham","Huntsville",etc..)
```

so each q.QUERY loops through all the cities in the table every time

I am trying to find all the rows that has values of city

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this, assuming you don't want duplicate rows if the query column contains several cities:

```
select q.query, f.anonid 
from facts f
inner join querydim q on f.queryid = q.id 
where exists (select 1 from zipcodes where locate(city, q.query));
```

The `locate` function searches for the first string in the second string, returning the index if found, zero otherwise, and zero converts to false.

Comment: I timed out. the q.query are alot like 100 thousands. might that be the issue abd the zicodes table has multiple columns

Comment: Nah, the query is rather heavy as it has to test every city in zip codes towards every query...

Answer (score 0):

You could use LIKE operator and   a full join on zipcodes

```
SELECT q.QUERY, f.ANONID 
FROM FACTS f
INNER JOIN QUERYDIM q ON f.QUERYID = q.ID 
INNER JOIN  ( SELECT city FROM zipcodes ) t on q.query like concat('%',t.city, '%');
```

Comment: should the full join , join on something ?

Comment: answer  updated ..  mysql don'use full join

Comment: I timed out. the q.query are alot like 100 thousands. might that be the issue abd the zicodes table has multiple columns